# How to get the number of males and females with a particular blood group

Tags: mysql, sql

**Schema of Donor and Acceptor Table**

[image]

[image]
**I have two tables 1st Donor and 2nd Acceptor. I need to get the total number of males and females with a particular blood group**

**This is the sample input and output

Can someone help me on how to query it using MYSQL?
Thanks**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` the `UNION` of both tables. For example:

```
select
  gender, gb, count(*)
from (
  select gender, bg from donor
  union all
  select gender, bg from acceptor
) x
group by gender, gb
```